# .filter and .map to occur only when length is greater than 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to achieve the following:

For each object in addedExtra, if the field applicableOnProduct is empty, then I still want it to be rendered on the page however lets say an object that does have content in applicableOnProduct (length > 0) then it's only where I want the .filter and .map check to happen.

How do I do this in React?

```js
const addedExtra = [{
    name: 'Bed Sheet',
    applicableOnProduct: [],
    selected: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Pillows',
    applicableOnProduct: [],
    selected: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Luxury Bet Set',
    applicableOnProduct: [{
      title: 'Luxury Bed',
      productId: '857493859049'
    }],
    selected: false
  },
];

return (
  {addedExtra
    .filter(({ applicableOnProduct}) =>
      applicableOnProduct.some(({ productId}) => productId === product.id)
    )
    .map((extra) => {
      return <Extra {...extra}></Extra>;
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Please try: `.filter(.... => applicableOnProduct.length === 0 || ....).map()`

Comment: This worked! You should really post it as an answer so I can mark it as the solution :) @jsN00b